# How the server really handle the response to a http request?

Tags: http, web, server

I understand that the server send website components to the client after http request, HTML, CSS, Js and other static files that are necessary to build the website in the client browser.

I want to understand what the server actually do to generate the response since it should handle many requests not just one request??

I assume that the server create an instance from the files and send it to the client via http response?? is this right, wrong,inaccurate or incomplete or are there other processes that happen on the server to make it work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "website components" (code for the browser) can be created by the server however it wants. There are two typical patterns. Static and dynamic.

Static resources are created ahead of time. These cannot be customised by the server at the time of the request.

Dynamic resources will be generated when the request is received. For example, a HTML asset may be generated to include a particular user's username as found in a cookie sent with the request. This is typically done from templates like jinja2 for Python.

Nowadays serving these resources statically and using a client side JavaScript application with a separate data API to customise content is the most popular way to build interactive websites (web apps)

Comment: If you are interested in learning more about how servers respond to requests and you are already familiar with JavaScript then I recommend picking up Express JS. There are plenty of good tutorials online